# Sort data using Elastic Search Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can anyone help me how I can sort my data given below JSON object using java API:

```
{
    "sites": [
        {
            "siteId": "1",
            "siteName": "Site 1",
            "company": {
                "companyId": "1",
                "companyName": "Test Company"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalHitsCount": 1
}
```

This works by sorting the data with siteName but if I want to do it by companyName then how can I do it?

`searchSourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("siteName").order(SortOrder.ASC));`

Answer (score 0):

Nested sorts are not supported yet by Spring Data Elasticsearch. There is an [issue addressing this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1783).